# How can I open a Microsoft Access Database file with an .exe?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ms-access

I have been working on creating a pretty advanced GUI enabled database in Microsoft Access and am now in the implementation phase of my project.

My dream is to make an .exe file that will point to the actual .accdb database file (which will be hidden) as I cannot change the icon of the .accdb but will be able to modify the .exe's icon thus giving my implementation a more professional feel.

I'd prefer not to just create a shortcut to the .accdb and change that icon.

Through some quick digging, my plan was  to create a .bat file that opens the .accdb and then use some online ".bat to .exe" converter to then add an icon to the .exe.

I can't figure out how to create a .bat file that opens my .accdb. I've tried a variety of different things like:

> start "" C:\Program Files (x86)\CompassTrack "Science Department.accdb"

and other things that dont work.

It occurred to me that a .bat to .exe approach may not be the best way to do this. I don't particularily like the brief command prompt window appearance and would be open to any suggestions as to how to get a nice looking .exe file to open my .accdb.

If the best way really is a .bat file, I'd appreciate some help with the .bat file. The path to the file is C:\Program Files (x86)\CompassTrack\Science Department.accdb but for some reason every time, command prompt would return "Cannot find C:\Program "

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to learn how quotes work. `start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\CompassTrack\Science Department.accdb"`

Answer (score 0):

to change icon of an exe file using batch, look [here](http://wikihow.com/Change-the-Icon-for-an-Exe-File)

and to start your file use:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\CompassTrack"
start "" "Science Departement.accdb"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just change the icon of your Access database. Go to Current Database (in recent versions under Office Button > Access Options) and the option is in there.

Comment: I appreciate it.

This option was modified/disabled in the newer versions of Access and in Windows 8+ from what I've read

Comment: I've checked in Access 2013 and Windows 10 and it works fine there. Are you sure? It might just be hard to find with the menus-totally-change-every-version thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple C# program that you can compile into an exe very easily to if you have .NET 3.5 installed. it uses a utility called the command line compiler. You'll have to change the file path obviously.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

public class App
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:/your_file_path_goes_here/YourDB.accdb";
        myProcess.Start();              
    }
}
```

You'll write the above to a text file with the extension `.cs`. Then create a batch file (a text file with the extension .bat) with this code.

```
@echo OFF
echo Compiling A File . . .
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe /win32icon:_.ico /target:winexe /recurse:*.cs
echo.
@pause
```

Put these in the same dir as whatever icon you want to use, but make sure the icon is an iso file named _, as seen in the batch program. When you run the bat file, it will create the exe with the icon of your choice and it will simply launch the access database.

Answer (score 0):

The feature and ability is part of the Access development system. Attempting to modify some .exe file etc. will not work.

I do suggest that you set the icon under file->options current database. It not clear why this is not working (perhaps start a new question to resolve that issue).

Keep in mind that if you deploy or change the resulting location, then you have to change the above “options” setting (manually, or by code – this much explain why your icon is not displaying – the path name cannot be relative – must be absolute.

ALSO select the box that says to use the icon for all forms and reports (this will give your application a MUCH more polished look. Since the .exe that actually runs your file is msacces.exe, then you can’t really change the application icon any other way. You see icons for the application AND ALSO forms like this "when" you set the application icon as per above:

[image]

So you WILL want to set the application icon. You then create a shortcut on your desktop. And again set the icon for that windows shortcut (it will nicely show up in the task bar with that icon).

The actual shortcut will look much like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE"
"c:\RidesDev\SkiRides\ RidesXP.accde" /runtime
```

The above shortcut will be on a single line (space between the two lines). The above is for Access 2010, so for 2013, then the folder is office15, and for 2016, it is office16 in above.

Also NOTE very important is the /runtime. This will ensure that the access icon NEVER shows during start-up.

Also, during start-up you will often see the MS Access splash logo during start-up. E.g. this:

[image]

You can replace this splash screen by placing a .bmp (picture) file in the SAME folder as the accDE with the same name.

So in above, if I place a RidesXMP.bmp picture file, then during start-up in place of the access splash screen, you see this:

[image]

Since you likely want the forms + reports icon to be custom, then the above makes the most sense. Your approach would ONLY give you a desktop icon, not one for the task bar, forms etc.

The above will result in hiding the access splash logo during start-up, and also apply an icon to all forms etc. I don’t suggest some approach that attempts to modify some .exe or some such – that’s likely to cause issues on customers computers. And using some .exe will not give you the icon for forms and repots.